# Hibernate hangs at session.createQuery.list

Tags: hibernate

Below is my code

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected List<String> executeTestQuery(final String query)
{
    List<String> ret;

    Session session = factory.openSession();
       try
    {
          ret = session.createQuery(query).list();//HANGS
     }
    finally
    {

        session.flush();

       session.close();

    }
    return ret;
}
```

Above method is common method which is getting called from every method and also  recursively in some cases.  
Hibernate hangs at mentioned point after few run. 
 I even added
  `config.setProperty(Environment.C3P0_MAX_SIZE, "100");`
 
 `session.clear(), SessionFactoryUtils.releaseSession(session, factory);`

Still no use.
Any suggestion for above problem would be a great help.

Comment: <code>select def.id from Definition def where def.type.name = 'XXX'<code>

Comment: Going to need to show waaaaay more information.  The 2 most likely culprits are (1) db lock contention and (2) large eager fetch graph (n+1).  If it hangs indefinitely, the locks are the most likely.  Check locks in you db; for eager problems enable Hibernate's SQL logging and see how many statements are executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanx guys for your help.Finally problem got resolved.  Problem was not with the mentioned function .  Problem was with the calling function and it's session was never getting closed .session.flush and session.close solved the problem.

Comment: as I can see you are already closing session in above method. So how you solved this as I am also facing same kind of problem

Comment: @DhruvPal I just had similar problem. (for me createQuery was hanging even when first called)  Netbeans debuger simply gave up somewhere in internals of createQuery.  After whole day of unsucceful tries I try adding:
`Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();`
after the:
`Session session = factory.openSession();`
and It started working I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Try using getCurrentSession() of SessionFactory.